# In XmlRpc The addHandler method of WebServer class in JAVA is deprecated what is the other alternative for this method?

Tags: java, server, client, xml-rpc

I know that this question has already been asked .In the previously asked questions there is a link from where we can find the details about org.apache.xmlrpc but I cound not determine the alternative for addHandler method of WebServer class.

I have two projects

```
    1    Server
            Server project consist of
                1.1 AreaServer
                1.2 AreaHandler
    2   Client
            Client project consist of
        2.1 Client
```

AreaHandler class copmutes the area of the circle for a given radius.
AreaServer uses AreaHandler class.

**AreaServer**

```
package webtutorial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer;

/**
 *
 * @author Dev Parzival
 */
public class AreaServer {
    public static void main(String $[]){
        try {
            startServer($);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AreaServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public static void startServer(String $[]) throws IOException{
        WebServer server;
        server=new WebServer(Integer.parseInt($[0]));
        server.addHandler("area",new AreaHandler());
        server.start();
    }
}
```

**AreaHandler**

```
package webtutorial;

/**
 *
 * @author Dev Parzival
 */
public class AreaHandler {
    
    /**
     *
     * @param radius radius of circle whose area has to be computed
     * @return area of the circle whose type is double
     */
    public double circleArea(double radius){
        return Math.PI*radius*radius;
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
package client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;

/**
 *
 * @author Dev Parzival
 * @date   02-Sep-2020
 * @time   08:46:01
 */
public class Client {

    /**
     * @param $ the command line arguments , represent the radius of the circle whose area is to be computer via the server.
     */
    public static void main(String[] $) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Client client=new Client();
        double radius=Double.parseDouble($[0]);
        try{
            double area=client.areaCircle(radius);
            System.out.println("Area of the circle is : "+area);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    public double areaCircle(double radius) throws IOException,XmlRpcException{
        double area=0;
        XmlRpcClient client=new XmlRpcClient();
        ArrayList<Double> vec=new ArrayList<Double>();
        vec.add(new Double(radius));
        Object result=client.execute("area.circleArea", vec);
        area=Double.parseDouble(result.toString());
        return area;
    }
}
```

The addHandler method is deprecated so I want to know how can do this

```
server.addHandler("area",new AreaHandler());
```

Link the AreaHandler class with area So when client request the server it returns the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use deprecated methods. What version of xmlrpc are you using?

The docs indicate that you can use `PropertyHandlerMapping` to add mappings from a property file.

```
      PropertyHandlerMapping phm = new PropertyHandlerMapping();
      /* Load handler definitions from a property file.
       * The property file might look like:
       *   Calculator=org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.Calculator
       *   org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.proxy.Adder=org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.proxy.AdderImpl
       */
     phm.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
               "MyHandlers.properties");
     xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(phm);
```

Or you can add them directly:

```
      /* You may also provide the handler classes directly,
       * like this:
       * phm.addHandler("Calculator",
       *     org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.Calculator.class);
       * phm.addHandler(org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.proxy.Adder.class.getName(),
       *     org.apache.xmlrpc.demo.proxy.AdderImpl.class);
       */
```

See: https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html

You can still add a handler, like this:

```
WebServer server = new WebServer(Integer.parseInt($[0]));
PropertyHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new PropertyHandlerMapping();
handlerMapping.addHandler("area", AreaHandler.class);
XmlRpcServer xmlRpcServer = webServer.getXmlRpcServer();
xmlRpcServer.setHandlerMapping(handlerMapping);

XmlRpcServerConfigImpl serverConfig = (XmlRpcServerConfigImpl) xmlRpcServer.getConfig();
serverConfig.setEnabledForExtensions(true);
serverConfig.setContentLengthOptional(false);

server.start();
```

Comment: the jar version is 3.1.3

Comment: Can you share the link for the older version of xmlrpc jar files so it will support addHandler method

Comment: Updated answer, you should still be able to add the handler, but use the property handler mapping class to do it.

Comment: I am geting this error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer.newXmlRpcStreamServer(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.WebServer.<init>(Unknown Source) ;

Comment: at this line : server=new WebServer(Integer.parseInt($[0]));//$[0]=4404